# Thymeleaf: combine #strings functions

Tags: thymeleaf, template-engine

Is it possible to do something like this `th:attr="some-data=${#strings.replace(#strings.toLowerCase(object), '\\s', '-')}` - if so, is there a shorter way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That type of text manipulation is possible ... without the regex-expression (I think the problem with regex here is that thymleaf escapes the expression):

```
"${#strings.replace(#strings.toLowerCase(object), ' ', '-')}"
```

if you want to set a custom-attribute 'some-data' you can use:

```
th:attr="some-data=${#strings.replace(#strings.toLowerCase(object), ' ', '-')}"
```

or a little bit shorter for newer versions of tymeleaf:

```
th:some-data="${#strings.replace(#strings.toLowerCase(object), ' ', '-')}
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. My other problem was that I didn't know I had to use just one ``th:attr`` then separate the data's by comma. Thanks!